# setgroups operation not permitted

Tags: linux, apache, openshift, sudo, rhel

I'm running an apache container in openshift. I'm following instructions similar to this to run as a user (in this case apache)
https://www.openshift.com/blog/jupyter-on-openshift-part-6-running-as-an-assigned-user-id
That seems unrelated because the error shows openshift is running the container as the expected user and not as an anonymous one. The only problem, is (setgroups operation not permitted). I have tried running the container as apache, daemon, root, and a new user. All of them give the same error:

```
daemon $ sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
error: failed switching to "root": setgroups operation not permitted
```

I've also tried

```
chmod 4777 /bin/su
```

To see if that would fix the error. It made no difference. I'm not sure on what my next steps should be.
Note that the container ran correctly in docker and in k8's although the modifications to /etc/passwd did not exist at the time. The base of the container is Centos

```
FROM cytopia/apache-2.2:0.9
```

Which is

```
FROM httpd:2.2
```